# A conjecture about twice continously differentiable functions.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in C^2[a,b]$, $f$ is not constant and $f$ takes it's maximum value(say $M$) also in $(a,b)$, then there is a point $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f''(c)<0$ and $f(c)=M$.

I could not prove it or find a counter example. If it is true it will help to prove strong maximum principle for harmonic functions without using mean value property.

Any hints and suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Can $M \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not true. Take for example $f(x)=-x^4$ on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: In fact, due to the existence of $e^{-1/x^2}$, the weakest hypothesis you can expect here is "analytic".